MongoDB C# Sort based on conditional column
I have an entity with 2 dates, something like this simplified entity:
public sealed class Foo
{
    public DateTime DateA { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateB { get; set; }
}

I need to sort according this rule:

The date of the Foo entity is the farthest of DateA and DateB

I tried to write some code, respecting this rule:
Builders<Foo>.Sort.Ascending(x => x.DateA > x.DateB ? x.DateA : x.DateB));

But the operation is not supported at runtime, is there another way to do this?

You can't sort on an expression. So first create a field with that value - using the larger date between DateA & DateB (aka  "most recent", or  newest). For this, you can use  $cond  with if-then-else but since you have actual Date-type fields, it's  simpler to use the  $max  operator. I don't know C# but this is what the aggregation pipeline should be.

Afaik, you can't use $addFields or $set in C# so you'd need to use that as a BsonArray of aggregation pipeline stages. new BsonArray { new BsonDocument("$set", new BsonDocument("largestDate", new BsonDocument("$max", new BsonArray { "$DateA", "$DateB" }))), new BsonDocument("$sort", new BsonDocument("largestDate", 1)), new BsonDocument("$unset", "largestDate") }

@aneroid, you can use $addFields and $set, but for this you have to specify it in a raw form via AppendStage method
